# Matrices as product space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If for each $i$ in some index set $I$ we have a vector space $V_i$ (all over the same field $F$), then their Cartesian product $\times_{i \in I}V_i$ is a vector space with addition and scalar multiplication defined indexwise.

If, for positive integers $m$ and $n$ we take index set $I=\{1, \ldots, m\}\times \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and the associated vector spaces equal to our field $F$, it follows that the set of functions that assign to each pair $(i,j)$ in our index set a number $a_{ij}$ in $F$ is a vector space.

But that would just be an $m\times n$ matrix, yet without reference to the usual notation with rows and columns.

**Question:** Is it correct to treat matrices as such product spaces? To be more precise, I do, of course, realise the use of rows and columns and the associated discussions of things like row and column spaces, but as a proof that matrices over a field constitute a vector space, would the argument above suffice?

Comment: Yes, as a vector space, a matrix space is just the $mn$-fold product space. The $m\times n$ array structure is important for defining, for example, matrix multiplication, but that plays no role in its vector space structure and may safely be forgotten for that discussion

Comment: Yes in fact this is how matrices are formally defined in some treatments.